# Filtering rows from Matrix based on values of all cells of the row

Tags: r

I have the following matrix

```
> mat1 <- matrix(c(3,1,2,2,2,1,1,3,4,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,4,4,3,1), nrow = 4)
> mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    4    1    4
[2,]    1    1    3    3    4
[3,]    2    1    1    1    3
[4,]    2    3    2    2    1
```

I would like to keep rows which have at least 3 even numbers :

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[2,]    1    1    3    3    4
[3,]    2    1    1    1    3
```

I know i can do it using bucles, is there any easier and faster way to do it? Something like basic filtering. I tried this, but didnt work:

```
mat1[evenCounts(mat1[,-1])>=3,]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even numbers can be identified using `mat1 %% 2 == 0`. Even numbers in a row can be counted using `rowSums`.

```
mat1[rowSums(mat1 %% 2 == 0) >= 3, ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3    2    4    1    4
#[2,]    2    3    2    2    1
```

Similarly, for odd numbers you can do -

```
mat1[rowSums(mat1 %% 2 == 1) >= 3, ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    3    3    4
#[2,]    2    1    1    1    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
> subset(mat1, rowSums(1 - mat1 %% 2) > 2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    4    1    4
[2,]    2    3    2    2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `Reduce`

```
 mat1[Reduce(`+`, lapply(asplit(mat1, 2), `%%`, 2)) < 3,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    4    1    4
[2,]    2    3    2    2    1
```